# Use Column Value as key and another Column Value as dict from django ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

In Django, I am trying an output without using a for loop to optimise the operation.

My model structure seems like this

```
class Test(BaseClass):
    id = model.UUIDField(uniq=True)
    ref = models.ForeignKey(Ref)
    name = model.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Sample data in the table

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------+
|                  id                  | ref_id |      name      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------+
| 412dacb1-6451-4a1a-b3ac-09a30979b733 |      1 | test           |
| fa7abc8e-2070-40b6-af84-6a8d78676b89 |      2 | new_rule       |
| dd70a968-778c-4e45-9044-599effd243a6 |      3 | new_rule_test |
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------+
```

And I need to output in dict something like this

```
{
  1: {
    "name": "test",
    "id": UUID(412dacb1-6451-4a1a-b3ac-09a30979b733)
  },
  2: {
    "name": "new_rule",
    "id": UUID(fa7abc8e-2070-40b6-af84-6a8d78676b89)
  },
  3: {
    "name": "new_rule_test",
    "id": UUID(dd70a968-778c-4e45-9044-599effd243a6)
  }
}
```

In the above output, the key is `ref_id` and the value is again a dict having name and id.

I have tried with `annotate` but it is not working. Only the below code which is working but I need more optimised as the data is very massive.

```
res_dict = Test.objects.filter(publisher_state='Published').values('ref', 'name', 'id')
final_dict = {row['ref']: {'name': row['name'], 'id':row['id']} for row in res_dict}
```

Comment: I was wondering why you need that format of dictionary output? How are you using that dictionary?

Comment: So, this dict is going to use to map and get data from another source. From which we cannot query. So by this the search on ref_id would be faster than to loop the data

Comment: In that case, I do not think there is a way to improve this performance issue by code. I would consider using caching or memory based DB for storing this data for other source to use this data.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Optimization:

```
from django.db.models import F
queryset = Test.objects.all().values('ref_id', 'name', 'id')
result = queryset.annotate(ref_name=F('ref__name')).values('ref_id', 'name', 'id', 'ref_name')

final_dict = {}
for row in result:
    final_dict[row['ref_id']] = {'name': row['name'], 'id': row['id'], 'ref_name': row['ref_name']}
```

**explanation**:
By using this method, you can improve the efficiency of your code compared to the original approach. This is achieved by reducing the amount of data that needs to be fetched from the database and eliminating the need for a separate loop to construct the final dictionary.

Comment: I don't required ```ref_name``` so I think we can eliminate ```ref__name``` and then the query will become same as mention in the question